# Error while using Telerik namespace names not found schedule view

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight-5.0, wpftoolkit, telerik-scheduler

I am doing one implementation where I need to have appointment schedule page, so I took information from Telerik and taken codes from Telerik website from the link below. So I created a new project and used the same code in my silverlight, fixed many issues with respect to dll, but there is an issue with the namespace adding in XAML file, I am attaching 3 images, where it shows what the namespace I have used and project list, please let me know what I am missing and what I should do to fix it,if any other information needed please let me know, happy to share

**Edit1**

**I know what does the error says, but I have doubt on my project name namespace i.e. last line of my xaml page, so this is the image where have error list with namespace not found**

**Edit2**

This is the part of my " OrientedGroupHeaderContentTemplateSelector " class

[image]

### [image: Error List]

These are the Images

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

[ScheduleView](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#ScheduleView/DragDrop)

Comment: Did you try to run it? The XAML editor sometimes shows errors that aren't errors. Also, closing the XAML tab and running then can work too.

Comment: Hi Loetn, Yep I did tried build and run, but gets error messages

Comment: Can you show the `OrientedGroupHeaderContentTemplateSelector`  code?

Comment: I wish I could, but the code or OrientedGroupHeaderContentTemplateSelector is more, what do you suggest to send the code ??

Comment: Ok. The namespace in your `OrientedGroupHeaderContentTemplateSelector` is correct? And your constructor is public?

Comment: Yep, That's true namespace is correct and the constructor is Public, please see the latest image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60165/discussion-between-manjuboyz-and-loetn).